# WindowManager, View animation copy

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I have a view that is movable. Also it is attached to windowmanager. How can I manage to make window to which attached my view copy every movement of my view so it would always travel with my view?

I use this to move my view:

```
private class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener{
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            switch (motionEvent.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    dX = view.getX() - motionEvent.getRawX();
                    dY = view.getY() - motionEvent.getRawY();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    view.animate()
                            .x(motionEvent.getRawX() + dX)
                            .y(motionEvent.getRawY() + dY)
                            .setDuration(0)
                            .start();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if(view.getX()>(windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()/2)){
                        view.animate().x(windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() - view.getWidth())
                                .y(view.getY())
                                .setDuration(0)
                                .start();
                    }else{
                        view.animate().x(0)
                                .y(view.getY())
                                .setDuration(0)
                                .start();
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

My code for attaching button to window:

```
        Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_button));
        b.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        windowManager.addView(b, params);
```